# Can't auto-connect to hidden WiFi network from iPhone

Tags: iphone, wireless-networking

I have access to a WiFi-network with SSID broadcast disabled and protected using WEP. It works great to connect to the WLAN-network manually using the iPhone, but I have to do it manually every time. The iPhone doesn't remember the network and password, why is that? I'm using iPhone OS 3.0.1 on my 3GS.

Comment: Just so you know: hiding a wireless network name does not help to improve security -- http://blogs.technet.com/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx (and WEP is not secure either).

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the security limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try Resetting all Network Settings, it usually works. Alternatively, try using a $ before your password, i.e., enter $password.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the dollar sign? What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to the iPhone only. It is not implemented by Apple in the Mac OS X as well. See: [Automatically Connecting to Hidden SSID WiFi Network](https://superuser.com/questions/43836/automatically-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-wifi-network) Not that it helps you, but at least you can see you are not the only one :)