# How to make my WiFi connection hidden?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, security

I have noticed in Ubuntu a command called **Connecting to a hidden wireless network**. These hidden networks do not broadcast their names, which means that they will not show up in the list of wireless networks in the NetworkManager menu.

How can I make my WiFi connection hidden in order to make it more secure? Is there any way to do that in a home conditions?

Comment: I don't think I should post this as an answer since it's not an answer to your question. "Hiding" the SSID won't do what you probably think it will do. I recommend you take a look at this answer to another question: http://superuser.com/questions/43836/automatically-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-wifi-network/48280#48280 Also this link provided in a comment below that answer: http://blogs.technet.com/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx

Comment: Hiding your SSID does not do much to improve security. It is like taking the number off your front door and thinking that you won't get burgled because burglars will not to be able to find your house.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can stop the router from broadcasting the SSID, it does nothing at all to make your network more secure. Your computer and the router are still communicating wirelessly, and the data they send is going out over the open air -- there is no way to stop anyone from gathering it and listening. What you can do to enhance security is use strong encryption on your network. Set it to WPA2 with a good cipher and you'll be fine. There's no known vulnerabilities in WPA2, so the only way for someone to break into the network is to gather lots of packet data and try to brute-force your password. Practice strong password security and it's highly unlikely anyone will get in.

Answer (score 4):

Set your wireless router to not broadcast its SSID.  However, this doesn't significantly improve security; if you want that, use encryption.  Then you'll have to know and enter a "password" or key in order to connect, and no one without the key will be able to use the router.