# Windows 7 - saved wifi access points disappear from list

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm having a weird issue with Windows 7 x64: I'm moving my notebook between two locations weekly, at each I have a wifi router. They both have hidden SSID-s, which are different.

If I save one, the other one gets deleted from the list, as if overwritten, so I always have to retype the SSID and password, if I want to connect after moving my computer.

At first I tought the problem was caused by both routers having the same password, but after I changed one (suffixed it with "_2") it persisted.

What can I do about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a feature. (maybe) Windows does not save your password for (multiple) Hidden SSIDs.

Hidden SSIDs mostly do not increase security and can add risk in some cases. Consider looking into this.

speculation:
If your computer were to save a hidden SSID, it would have to be always shouting "HELLO IS ANYONE ROUTER45!" and then a malicious router could say "hey that's me!"

Perhaps you might be able (unwisely) to go through the wizard and make it connect "even when not broadcasting" re: The last screenshot on this page: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/02/08/non-broadcast-wireless-ssids-why-hidden-wireless-networks-are-a-bad-idea.aspx

Other relevant info:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653/debunking-myths-is-hiding-your-wireless-ssid-really-more-secure/

And especially:
[Automatically Connecting to Hidden SSID WiFi Network](https://superuser.com/questions/43836/automatically-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-wifi-network)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.
I'll try if unhiding the SSID solves my problem and accept your answer if it does.
(Though my old laptop worked this way, so it's still a bit weird.)