# Remember login credentials of Hidden SSID WiFi Network on OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac

This question is really similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/43836/automatically-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-wifi-network)

where it was asked:

> My MacBook Pro will not automatically connect to a Wireless network with a hidden SSID. It makes me select the "Join Other Network..." in the Airport menu (in the system tray), where I need to input the name of the network, then security type, password and wait for it to connect. This is becoming increasingly annoying to have to do every time I come back to my desk.
>
> How do I make my MacBook Pro automatically connect to a WiFi Network with a hidden SSID without having to "configure" it every time I want to connect?

Now the top answer there is a long explanation why you wouldn't want to automatically connect to the Network. And I accept that it is a bad idea to auto connect. This question is not about auto connecting but about manually connecting.

However what I do find annoying is that everytime I would like to manually connect to it using the "Join other network..." option, I have to manually enter the SSID, the network security type and the password. These three steps are really annoying and I would like to be able to just connect to this hidden network by selecting it from a list of networks, and have OS X remember all the authentication credentials, because having to remember and retype the secure password every time is becoming annoying.

So to be clear this question is about making the manual connection process less laborious, so that connecting to the network is just two clicks instead of filling in all details into the same form over and over again.

Comment: I doubt there's anything new to be added to the existing Q/A. It's still a bad idea to have hidden SSIDs with auto-connect, as that means you're constantly asking the AP if it's there; completely negating the supposed 'security' of hiding it. Either set up a script as mentioned, or better still, unhide the SSID.

Comment: I think this is really a duplicate of [Automatically Connecting to Hidden SSID WiFi Network](https://superuser.com/questions/43836/automatically-connecting-to-hidden-ssid-wifi-network) & the answers there are still valid.

Comment: Your failure to grasp or appreciate the facts noted in the answers to the duplicate question does not change the fact those answers are correct. Systems specifically do not automatically connect to hidden SSID for the reasons noted there.

Comment: To all the three people commenting to my question, it is not about automatically connecting, I don't want to auto connect. I also explicitly state this in my question. I just want OS X to remember the password and authentication settings. So that connecting to the hidden network is just a question of selecting the hidden network from a saved list, instead of filling in all the authentication details again.

Comment: The linked question copntains a script to do just that. You're not going to persuade the OS to do it, because it's not in your best interests. Apple were considering it at one time, many years ago, but decided it was poor security so they left it out.